# How to track which case is selected and pass values to a function

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement, formula

This is a link to a working js [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u9b8zxxe/) in which

a) the user selects a category and accordingly the product drop down gets populated

b) based on the products the wattage is displayed. Both using switch statements

---

I am trying to learn how to do the foll:

1) Track a case inside productChange function. Which wattage is displayed on the page so that I can pass the numerical value of that wattage to a function  (Daily Energy consumption).

2) My end goal is to make sure my dailyEnergyConsumption function gets the  values it needs to do the calculation. I want to display it onClick of any of 4 buttons.

My attempt (direction / code / some pseudo code) is commented in JS. 
I have tried to define all the functions that I need.

Thanks !

```
    var category = document.getElementById('ddl'),
      product = document.getElementById('products'),
      wattage = document.getElementById('wattage'),
      refrigerators = new Array('Artic King AEB', 'Artic King ATMA', 'Avanti Compact', 'Bosch SS'),
      dishWasher = new Array('Bosch - SHXUC', 'Asko DS', 'Blomberg', 'Amana');

    var categoryChange = function() {
      switch (category.value) {
        case 'refrigerators':
          products.options.length = 0;
          for (i = 0; i < refrigerators.length; i++) {
            createOption(products, refrigerators[i], refrigerators[i]);
          }
          break;
        case 'dishWasher':
          products.options.length = 0;
          for (i = 0; i < dishWasher.length; i++) {
            createOption(products, dishWasher[i], dishWasher[i]);
          }
          break;
        default:
          products.options.length = 0;
          break;
      }

      productChange();
    }

    var productChange = function() {
      switch (product.value) {
        case 'Artic King AEB':
          wattage.innerHTML = 400;
          break;

        case 'Artic King ATMA':
          wattage.innerHTML = 500;
          break;

        case 'Avanti Compact':
          wattage.innerHTML = 340;
          break;

        case 'Bosch SS':
          wattage.innerHTML = 214;
          break;

        case 'Bosch - SHXUC':
          wattage.innerHTML = 200;
          break;

        case 'Asko DS':
          wattage.innerHTML = 187;
          break;

        case 'Blomberg':
          wattage.innerHTML = 236;
          break;

        case 'Amana':
          wattage.innerHTML = 150;
          break;

        default:
          wattage.innerHTML = 'N/A'
          break;
      }
    }

    function createOption(ddl, text, value) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value = value;
      opt.text = text;
      ddl.options.add(opt);
    }

    category.addEventListener('change', categoryChange);
    product.addEventListener('change', productChange);





    /* Attempt starts from below
     
    function findWattage(){

    // span on the page that displays wattage
     var wattage = document.getElementById('wattage');
        
    // created a new variable to find which case is selected.
     var wattageOnPage = wattage.something that will track which case is selected.value;
     
        // do i have to equate wattage with wattageOnPage
     
     // 
        return wattageOnPage;
    }


    function estimatedDailyUse(dailyUse){
      
       if(button.onclick.id =="h1"){
        return dailyUse = 1;
       }
     
       else if (button.onclick.id =="h3"){
        return dailyUse = 3;
       }
      
       else if (button.onclick.id =="h6"){
        return dailyUse = 6;
       }
       
       else if (button.onclick.id =="h24"){
        return dailyUse = 24;
      }
     
     }
     
      dailyEnergyConsumption = function() {

     // final display div
     var daily = document.getElementById('daily');
     
     //initialize the variable
     var dailyEnergyConsumed = 0;
     
     //Read the wattage that is displayed. 
     
     // Track the 4 buttons and gather which button is clicked and accordingly pass that to the formula
     
          
      // so whenever I will need the selected wattage I can call it like this and get value into my formula
        wattageOnPage = findWattage();
       
      //Formula (1,500 W × 1) ÷ 1,000 = 1.5 kWh
      var dailyEnergyConsumed = (wattageOnPage * dailyUse)/1000;
      
      //Display  and store 1.5 Kwh and pass it on to next function
      return dailyEnergyConsumed;
            daily.innerHTML = dailyEnergyConsumed;
      
    }
     

     
    /*
    annualEnergyConsumption = function(annualEnergy) {
     take the variable dailyEnergyConsumed and multiply that by no of days the user enters
     1.5 kWh × 365 (days) = 547.5 kWh
     Store it but do not display this
     Pass it to annual Cost function 
     */
    /*
     var annualEnergy=0;

     var text = document.getElementById('hour').value;
     var allYear = document.getElementById('allYear').value;

     var annualEnergy = dailyEnergyConsumed * text;
     return annualEnergy;
     
     
    } 
    */

    /*
    annualCost = function() {

     var utilityRate = document.getElementById('utilityRate').value;
     var button = document.getElementById('annualCost');
     var annualCostOperation = document.getElementById('annualCostOperation');

     var annualCost = ( annualEnergy * utilityRate);

     
     take var annualEnergy (547.5) K wh from annualEnergyConsumption function 
     capture what the user enters in Utility Rate textbox (11 cents per K Wh)
     
     ( Calculate 547.5 kWh × $0.11/kWh = $60.23/year)
     Click on the button to disaplay it
     
     

    }



    */
    #leftColumn {
      width: 500px;
      float: left;
    }
    .placeholderText {
      font: bold 12px/30px Georgia, serif;
    }
    body {
      padding-left: 45px;
    }
    #annualEnergyConsumption {
      font: bold 25px arial, sans-serif;
      color: #00ff00;
    }
    #annualCostOperation {
      font: bold 40px arial, sans-serif;
      color: #00ff00;
    }
    .dailyButInline {
      display: inline;
    }
    /* mouse over link */

    button:hover {
      background-color: #00ff00;
    }
    /* selected link */

    button:active {
      background-color: #00ff00;
    }
    <h2>Annual Energy Consumption and Cost Calculator</h2>

    <form id="costForm">
      <div id="leftColumn">
        <div> <span class="placeholderText">Choose Category</span>
          </br> <span>
    <select id="ddl">
    <option value="">Select a Category</option>
    <option value="refrigerators">Refrigerators</option>
    <option value="dishWasher">DishWasher</option>
    </select>
     </span>

          </br>
          </br>
        </div>
        <div> <span class="placeholderText">Select a Product</span>
          </br> <span>
     <select id="products">
       <option selected>--------------------------</option>
     </select>
     </span>

          </br>
          </br>
        </div>
        <div> <span class="placeholderText">Wattage</span>
          </br> <span id="wattage">Select a Category and product to view its wattage</span>

          </br>
          </br>
        </div>
        <div id="buttonBoundary">
          <div class="placeholderText">Estimated Daily Use</div>
          <div class="dailyButInline">
            <button type="button" id="h1" onclick="estimatedDailyUse(this)">Not a Lot 1 hour per day</button>
          </div>
          <div class="dailyButInline">
            <button type="button" id="h3" onclick="estimatedDailyUse(this)">Average</br>3 hour per day</button>
          </div>
          <div class="dailyButInline">
            <button type="button" id="h6" onclick="estimatedDailyUse(this)">A Lot</br>6 hour per day</button>
          </div>
          <div class="dailyButInline">
            <button type="button" id="h24" onclick="estimatedDailyUse(this)">Always On</br>24 hours per day</button>
          </div>
          </br>
          </br>
        </div>
        <div> <span class="placeholderText">Daily Energy Consumption</span>
          </br>
          <div id="daily">0.268 kWh</div>
          </br>
        </div>
        <div> <span class="placeholderText">Approximate Days used per year</span>
          </br>
          <div id="daysUsed">
            <input type="number" id="hour" maxlength="2" min="1">
            </br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="allYear" />
            <label for="allYear">All year</label>
          </div>
          </br>
        </div>
        <div> <span class="placeholderText">Annual Energy Consumption</span>
          </br>
          <div id="annualEnergyConsumption">547.5 kWh</div>
          </br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <div> <span class="placeholderText">Enter your Utility Rate per Kw/h</span>
          </br> <span><input type="number" id="utilityRate" /></span>

          </br>
          </br>
        </div>
        <div> <span class="placeholderText"><button id="annualCost" onclick="annualCost()">Annual Cost to Operate</button></span>
          </br><span id="annualCostOperation" /></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thanks@Ortomala. I am reading this. (I am recently self taught. This should not be a surprise.).